# Let $f_1, f_2: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be lower semicontinuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f_1+f_2$ is lower semicontinuous at $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_1, f_2: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be lower semicontinuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f_1 + f_2$ is lower semicontinuous at $a$. Assume that $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Prove that $h(x) = f_1(g(x))$ is lower semicontinuous at 1.

I am having trouble getting started with this proof and can't do the second part without first understanding how to show that $f_1 + f_2$ is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Use [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) while posting something here.

Answer (score 0):

To answer only the first question:  Lower semicontinuous at $a$ is defined, it seems, to mean that if $a_n\to a$ then $\liminf f(a_n)\geq f(a)$.  (Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 2.8 uses a different definition, presumably equivalent.)  In other words, lower semicontinuous means that for any $a_n\to a$, given any $\epsilon>0$, we have $f(a_n)\geq f(a)-\epsilon$ for $n\geq$ some $N$.

Applied to $f_1$ and $f_2$, this means that for $a_n\to a$, given $\epsilon>0$, we have $f_1(a_n) \geq f_1(a)-\epsilon$ and $f_2(a_n) \geq f_2(a)-\epsilon$ for $n\geq$ some $N$. We then have $(f_1+f_2)(a_n)\geq (f_1+f_2)(a)-2\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, and $a_n$ was any sequence that goes to $a$, this means we have $\liminf (f_1+f_2)(a_n) \geq (f_1+f_2)(a)$ as desired.